# Angular ui-router state doesn't change to home state on click of navbar icon

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using ui-router to navigate between pages using states. I have created tabs using states in different page called tabs.html. On changing state from home to mainTab i can successfully move to MainTab page and select the first tab(mainTab.tab1). But when i click the navbar icon to goto home page using $state.go(home), the state changes to the third tab( mainTab.tab3) and upon clicking the navbar again the state then changes to home.

How can this be avoided ?

Following is the code for the issue .

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: '',                       
        controller: ''
    })
    .state('mainTab', {
        url: '/mainTab',
        templateUrl: '',                       
        controller: '',
    })  
    .state("mainTab.tab1", {
        url:"mainTab/tab1",
        templateUrl: "",    
        controller: '',
    })
    .state("mainTab.tab2", {
        url:"mainTab/tab2",
        templateUrl: "",
        controller: '',
    })
    .state("mainTab.tab3", {
        url:"mainTab/tab3",
        templateUrl: "",
        controller: '',
    });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
```

});

This is how tabs are created :

```
$scope.tabs= [
  {
    heading: 'Tab1',
    route:   'mainTab.tab1',
    active:false
  },
  {
    heading: 'Tab2',
    route:   'mainTab.tab2',
    active:false
  },
  {
    heading: 'Tab3',
    route:   'mainTab.tab3',
    active:false
  }
];
```

tabs.html

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="page-wrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">          
            <tabset>
                <tab
                    ng-repeat="t in tabs"
                    heading="{{t.heading}}"
                    select="goTo(t.route)"
                    active="t.active"
                    >
                </tab>
            </tabset>
            <div ui-view></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

goTo() function is like this

```
$scope.goTo = function(route){ $state.go(route); }
```

Any inputs greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

try this, because when you are creating the route, its look like `mainTab/mainTab/tab1`. It takes parent state URL also.

```
$stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: '',
        controller: ''
    })
    .state('mainTab', {
        url: '/mainTab',
        templateUrl: '',
        controller: '',
    })
    .state("mainTab.tab1", {
        url: "/tab1",
        templateUrl: "",
        controller: '',
    })
    .state("mainTab.tab2", {
        url: "/tab2",
        templateUrl: "",
        controller: '',
    })
    .state("mainTab.tab3", {
        url: "/tab3",
        templateUrl: "",
        controller: '',
    });
```

Comment: Hi @Rahul, I tried the above code. Unfortunately it didnt work for me .Can you tell me what $scope.tabs should look like . Is it going to be same as above?

Comment: can you share `goTo()` also?

Comment: Here it is:     $scope.goTo = function(route){
        $state.go(route);
    };

Comment: then change `route: 'mainTab/tab1',` to `route:   'mainTab.tab1',`.  $state.go uses state name not url.

Comment: I am sorry it was an error on my behalf. route: 'mainTab.tab1'

Comment: @prakashpun Working now ?

Comment: I am still facing the same issue.

Comment: Hi @Rahul, there are no errors. The state just changes to the last tab and then on click of navbar icon again, it goes to home page